# traefik 1.7.X - Logging TLS version in access.log

Tags: ssl, logging, traefik

is there a way to determine the TLS Version in the traefik access.log.

We want to know how many requests are made with older TLS Versions.
I don't find any option to enable such a feature.
Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

traefik 1.7 is not able to log TLS verisons:
https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/logs/#list-of-all-available-fields .